# MDF File Size Not Growing

Tags: sql, filesize, mdf, ldf

I am having an issue with the MDF and IDF file sizes. I can see the physical file size paths are fine. It is set to auto-growth by 64 MB. The table sizes are changed frequently whereas MDF and LDF files sizes are still the same.
I am curious if it is some data loss or something which is not growing its size. I have any tables in the database and there are multiple transactions almost in each table every minute.
Can anyone in database expert help me out in this regard? I will be very thankful.

Comment: There is an initial size, maybe you have not exceed that, yet

Comment: @tinazmu Initial size is 131238 and the size in the disk is 131237.3125. If I decrease the initial size will the disk file size grow?

Comment: İf the data /index etc needs more storage than the initial size it will grow. did you learn about space usage reporting. SSMS has reports about how much each table is using

Comment: Yes I can see the space usage of each table.

Comment: And they should exceed the initial size? İf not, don't worry